# ASP.NET MVC6 Route Subdomain to Area

Tags: asp.net, azure, routes, subdomain, asp.net-mvc-areas

Has anyone figured out how to do this yet? I've spent countless hours on this site and there are not yet a solution. I'm currently in desperate need of knowledge.

I've created a routing handler and added the new route, it seems like Azure Websites aren't picking it up and routing it to a specific area for each sub domains hitting that IP.

Thanks, appreciates any insights I could get.

Comment: Can you show examples of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

By ASP.NET MVC6 I assume you mean ASP.NET Core? MVC6 was the name that had on the betas.

Areas are supported, just:

1. Create a folder named "Areas"
2. Inside, create your area (pick a name) and create a Controllers and Views folders.
3. Modify your `Startup.cs` file and change your `app.UseMvc` line with:

   ```
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
   routes.MapRoute("MyArea", "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/    {action=Index}/{id?}");

   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "default",
       template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
   });
   ```